# AcceptButton or CancelButton with UserControls VB

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, keyevent

I have a Form with a FlowLayoutpanel which adds several UserControls(TextBox+Label) in it. My Buttons(Accept/Close) are UserControls aswell.

How do I say my UserControl-Buttons that they're Buttons so that I can choose them in the Forms Properties as Accept-/CancelButton? Which property do I need for this?

Or how do I use the KeyPressEvent?

```
Private Sub OnKeyDownHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        MessageBox.Show("Enter key pressed")
    End If
End Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Me_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, _
ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyPress

    If (Control.ModifierKeys And Keys.Enter) = Keys.Enter Then
        MsgBox("enter key pressed")
    End If

End Sub
```

aren't triggered when I press Enter in this Form...

thanks in advance :)

Comment: do you have Keypreview set to True in the form?

Comment: Ohhh god - thank you very much...

this is embarrassing :>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is ages old, but in case someone comes across this, the proper way to create a `UseControl` that should act like a button is to implement the `System.Windows.Forms.IButtonControl` interface.  Once you've done that, you can select it as the Cancel/AcceptButton of the form.